# hexadecimal string to int conversion in C

Tags: c, string, int, hex

I have a text file with hexadecimal values, after I fscanf a value I need to know how I can convert it from hexadecimal string to an int. And then convert it back to hexadecimal string for a later print. Anyone knows an algorithm for this? thank you.

Comment: Why not just use `%x` in your format string ?

Comment: Use the %x format specifier instead of %s.

Comment: it doesn't work because I need to put the value in a variable of type int so when I use %x format I get an error after

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `%x` format specifier instead of `%s` to read your values. This will read the data as hexadecimal integers.

For example, if your file looks like this:

> ff3c 5a cb2d

Then you can read those 3 values like this:

```
int a, b, c;
fscanf(fp, "%x %x %x", &a, &b, &c); // a = 0xff3c, b = 0x5a, c = 0xcb2d
```

Comment: The problem with C is that it is not as type safe as C++. The error you are getting could be one of many problems. Either 1. you are telling the function it is expecting a DECIMAL integer (`%d`) but it is actually hexcadecimal and could contain letters (a-f) 2. `ProcTable[i].processPriority` is not an integer 3. `ProcTable[i].processPriority` is an integer but you are not taking the address of it (`&`)

Comment: @biz: This shouldn't give an error.  If you are getting an error, then please edit your question to include your *exact* code, and the error message/behaviour that you get.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `%x` format specifier in your `fscanf` and `fprintf` strings.

Answer (score 2):

As Marlon said above:

```
int a, b, c;
fscanf(fp, "%x %x %x", &a, &b, &c);
```

To print back as hex strings

```
fprintf(fp, "%x %x %x", a, b, c);
```

I think that you might be confused about the way the computer stores variables of type `int`.  They are not stored in base 10.  They are stored in binary, as I'm sure you know.  That means that there is nothing special about assigning a hex value to an `int`. It won't be stored any differently.  Using the `%x` just shows that you want the program to understand that the number you are giving it is a hex number (for example so it knows to store the string "10" as 10000(2) rather than as 1010(2).  Same thing with output. If your variable `a` has the binary 10000(2) and you print it using `%x`, the program knows that the output should be `10`. If you use `%d`, it knows that the output should be `16`.